# Vote for an answer to become accepted

Tags: feature-request, flagging

I'm tired of seeing bumps made by community. It's always questions made by one-timers making an account, receiving answers and leaving forever without accepting an answer. Many of those questions have answers that do solve the question asked, but because the person who asked the question has left the building and will never come back the right answer will never be accepted.

Is there any way to introduce some flag for answers that do solve the question asked? I don't have enough reputation to vote to close so I don't know exactly how that procedure works, but can there be something similar for an answer like "Vote to accept"?

I'm not aware of how much authority our moderators have, so this question might be all in vain, but there must be some way to get rid of the questions with answers? Right now I'm avoiding questions bumped by community.

Comment: You are unlikely to get change like this, because it would be implemented by SE, and the change would be implemented across all sites. If you do want a change, you can suggest it to meta.SE, but you'd better have a good reason and do research or your suggestion will get swatted down

Comment: I'd rather just ask for the possibility to block users, then I would be able to block community.

Comment: Your welcome to, ask on the SE meta and see how it goes.

Comment: I thought if there is an answer with +5 votes the question won't be considered unanswered. I don't remember if this is for Community bumps or the Unanswered question list, though.

Comment: @HarrySvensson: "*I'm a horrible writer.*" I think you mean, "I write horribly." I'm sure you are not horrible. ;^)

Comment: Well something has to be done about this. There are many users who don't respond to answers neither comments and take this community for granted. If you ask what is 2+2, and someone answers it as 4, of course that answer has to be unanimously accepted including OP.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nobody can mark an answer as accepted, except the author of the question.

If another user thinks the answer is good enough, they should upvote it. An upvoted answer is considered a satisfactory resolution of the question, even if it does not have a green check mark.

The feature to accept answers on behalf of another user was proposed about 100 times or more. It was declined as many times as it was proposed. A small sample:

- [Can a moderator set an accepted answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/232356/can-a-moderator-set-an-accepted-answer)
- [Allow users to mark "accepted" answer on someone else's question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26639/allow-users-to-mark-accepted-answer-on-someone-elses-question)
- [Moderators accepting answers on user's behalf after a certain time period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18312/moderators-accepting-answers-on-users-behalf-after-a-certain-time-period)
- [Feature request: moderator ability to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115263/feature-request-moderator-ability-to-accept-an-answer)
- [Flagging or moderator marking of relevant answers to mark it as "accepted"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144016/flagging-or-moderator-marking-of-relevant-answers-to-mark-it-as-accepted)
- [Should diamond mods have the ability to accept an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153294/should-diamond-mods-have-the-ability-to-accept-an-answer)
- [Marking someone elses question as answered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192147/marking-someone-elses-question-as-answered)

Comment: Then I assume that there's a really good reason for it, to decline it 100 times or more. Is it because it can't be done or because of ethical reasons?

Comment: Oh well, reading some of the other questions has given me some insight, but I still don't agree.

Comment: @HarrySvensson there are other Q&A sites like the MSDN forums which allow moderators to mark answers as accepted. At least 3 times now on MSDN I've asked a question only to get a generic answer which is then marked by a mod over there as the correct answer even when it is completely not the correct answer. Only the OP knows whether an answer is the answer to their specific question.

Comment: @tomcarpenter Which is why I want a voting system. That way one moderator can't make silly mistakes like that. But it doesn't matter. I've found a _solution_ to my problem. To never browse the questions on the front page, but only browse questions under the question tab. Community only bumps to the front page.

Comment: @HarrySvensson The *solution* to the problem is to vote up answers that answer the question. The system exists, you just need to use it.

Answer (score 9):

According to [this answer on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19739/193476), the Community bot only bumps

> Questions with at least 30 days of no activity, at least one answer scoring zero, and no answers scoring above that.

So if you want a question to stop being bumped, upvote an existing answer or provide a new answer that can be upvoted by others.

Comment: I am sure I have seen "community" bump posts that have not been accepted AND have a reply with at least 1 vote. Every time I see one I keep meaning to screenshot it and post in this meta but ... I lose this meta thread

Comment: @JonRB Maybe because the answer has been upvoted by someone else as a result of the bump, and before you look at it yourself. The posts stay long enough on the front page to give an opportunity for some other users to upvote, and this is exactly the prupose of the community bump. I do it sometimes. If you look at the timeline of the post, you'll be able to confirm this.

Answer (score -3):

Can we add an additional reason for voting to close a question, i.e. "No answer accepted within 90 days"?

If the question is a good one and worth keeping, it could be asked again by someone, answered by them and accepted and the original deleted.

I take the point that only the OP can say if their question has been answered, but if enough people consider that it has, it's probably more likely that the OP hasn't asked the right question in the first place.